# Filter query by Dates Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL, and I am having a difficulties filtering based on the date in my `WHERE` clause.

I am comparing the `date1` to `2018-01-01` and `2018-31-12`. All of the dates within this range should be displayed, but when I run my query nothing is displayed.

I would really appreciate any advice.

The `date1` datatype is `longtext`, and the `val` datatype is `longtext`.

```
date1                Val
2018-01-03           V1
2018-07-05           V2
2018-12-05           V3
2019-01-02           V4
2019-10-03           V5
```

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE date1 >= YEAR '2018-01-01' AND date1<= '2018-12-31'
```

Expected Output:

```
    date1                Val
    2018-01-03           V1
    2018-07-05           V2
    2018-12-05           V3
```

Comment: Hi really appeciate your response its a longtext

Comment: It is best practice to store date values as `date` or `datetime` datatypes.

Comment: I am sorry thank you for the advice really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error.

```
mysql> Select * from foo where date1 >= YEAR '2018-01-01' AND date1<= '2018-12-31' ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2018-01-01' AND date1<= '2018-12-31'' at line 1
```

`YEAR '2018-01-01'` is not valid syntax. It would have to be `YEAR('2018-01-01')`.

BTW your query is better written with `between`. Same thing, easier to read, less chance of bugs.

```
select * from foo where date1 between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31';
```